# htmlentities equivalent in jQuery template plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-templates

How can I convert special characters in a string to its equivalent htmlentities in [jQuery template plugin](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.template/)? I know about the `$('<div/>').text(str).html()` method in jQuery. I am looking for a way to implement it in the template plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want?

js code:

```
var data = { HtmlContent : '<h1>The h1 tag should not display</h>' };

$('#tmplSample').tmpl(data).appendTo('body');
```

template:

```
<script id="tmplSample" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
<div>
{{html HtmlContent}}
</div>
</script>
```

And here are some more samples:

http://api.jquery.com/template-tag-html/

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll have to use that trick manually when passing data to your templates.

```
$.tmpl (
    yourTemplate,
    {
        yourVar: $('<div/>').text(str).html()
    }
);
```